# Multiple pages in Eclipse android application

Tags: android, eclipse

i am new in this space i am working with mini app.
i have Animal images in Main template and want when click for example Dog image it must switch another page and there will be dog description and image gallery.
so i need to know how to create multiple pages and redirect it.
this is my app.
Thanks ...

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ////////////////////////  Dog
    Button button3 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final MediaPlayer dog = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // If the music is playing
            if(dog.isPlaying() == true)
                // Pause the music player
                dog.pause();
            // If it's not playing
            else
                // Resume the music player
                dog.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create differents activity for different pages.
And use Intent to change page.

Example :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivy.this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```